# Web Crypto : AES-GCM Decryption Failure in Ionic Application Background Mode?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webcrypto-api, ionic6

I’m currently facing a challenge with the Web Crypto API. While attempting to perform decryption, I’ve noticed that it functions as expected when the ionic application is in the foreground. However, when the application is moved to the background, the decryption process seems to halt, giving the impression that the application has frozen.

Interestingly, when I return the application to the foreground, I receive all the pending notifications at once. This behavior is puzzling and I’m seeking assistance to understand and resolve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
this.firebaseX.onMessageReceived()
            .subscribe(async data => {
                this.ngxLogger.info('PUSH: onMessageRecieved:'+JSON.stringify(data));
                this.initializeDebug("OnMessageRecived");

              
                let decryptedData = await Promise.resolve(this.decryptionService.decryptCipherData(data.data, data.ets));
                this.decryptedData = decryptedData;

                this.ngxLogger.info('Decrypted Alert ' + this.decryptedData);
      
            }, errRes => {
                console.log(' Error in receiveing message from Firebasex ' + JSON.stringify(errRes));
            });

   async decryptCipherData(data, ets) {


            var secretKey  = localStorage.getItem('secretKey1');
            var iv = localStorage.getItem('ivParameterSpec1');
           
            return this.decrypt(data, secretKey, iv);

       
    }

    async decrypt(data, secretKey, iv) {
        try {
            // Convert iv and ciphertext to Uint8Array
            var ivUint8Array = this.b64ToUint8Array(iv);
            var ciphertextUint8Array = this.b64ToUint8Array(data);

            // Import the CryptoKey
            this.ngxLogger.info('Importing the key!');
            console.log('Importing the key!')
            var key = await Promise.resolve(this.importKey(secretKey)).catch(e);

            // Decrypt using crypto.subtle.decrypt
            var decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                { name: 'AES-GCM', iv: ivUint8Array },
                key,
                ciphertextUint8Array
              );
          

            // Decode the decrypted data
            this.ngxLogger.info('Decode the decrypted data!');
            console.log('Decode the decrypted data!')
            var dec = new TextDecoder();
            var decryptedText = dec.decode(new Uint8Array(decrypted));

            console.log('Decrypted Text:', decryptedText);
            console.log('Decrypted Text:', JSON.stringify(decryptedText));
            return decryptedText;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Decryption failed:', error);
            console.log(error)
            return null;
        }
    }

    async importKey(secretKey) {
        try {
            this.ngxLogger.info('Parse the Base64-encoded key');
            console.log('Parse the Base64-encoded key')
            var keyBuffer = this.b64ToUint8Array(secretKey);

            // Import the key using crypto.subtle.importKey
            this.ngxLogger.info(' Import the key using crypto.subtle.importKey');
            console.log(' Import the key using crypto.subtle.importKey')
            var key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "raw",
                keyBuffer,
                { name: "AES-GCM" },
                true,
                ["decrypt", "encrypt"]
              );

            this.ngxLogger.info('Returning the key');
            console.log('Returning the key')
            return key;
        } catch (ex) {
            this.ngxLogger.info('Error');
            console.log('Error')
            this.ngxLogger.info('ImportKey error:', ex.name, ', Message:', ex.message);
            console.error('ImportKey error:', ex.name, ', Message:', ex.message);
            console.log(ex)
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Helper function
    b64ToUint8Array(base64string) {
        return Uint8Array.from(atob(base64string), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
    }
```

When the application is moved to the background, the decryption code fails to execute, resulting in decryption not functioning as intended.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour using `"jwk"`?

Comment: where is the code that runs this logic in the background with ionic? Ionic does not provide background mode out of the box, you need to add a plugin.

Comment: The requirement mandates the generation of a key utilizing AES-GCM, which takes place within the backend using Java. Don't think "jwk" will help in our situation. @guest271314

Comment: Before using AES-GCM encryption, our approach involved utilizing the CBC encryption algorithm and the CryptoJS library within the Ionic application for decryption. This issue did not arise during that time. However, due to the less secure nature of CBC, we decided to transition to GCM encryption and began employing the Web Crypto API since CryptoJS does not support GCM. Consequently, we are currently experiencing this issue.  @StackoverBlows

Comment: @Staha I don't have experience with ionic-framework. `"jwk"` worked for me when generating and importing keys in JavaScript using Web Cryptography API in Node.js, Deno, and Bun environments https://github.com/guest271314/webbundle/blob/main/generateWebCryptoKeys.js, https://github.com/guest271314/webbundle/blob/main/index.js#L11-L29, `"raw"` didn't . Good luck!